# how to refresh my itemlist in winapp when I insert a new data in sqlite (javascript & html)

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, winapp

I insert a new data into sqlite (with buttonclick) and then how to refresh my itemlist so that I can see the new data without restart the app. I use javascript&html to make a win8app.

I didn`t use databinding in the app.

```
 // Because we're doing the rendering, we need to put the data into the item.
        // We can't use databinding.
        result.getElementsByClassName("item-image")[0].src =currentItem.data.backgroundImage;
        result.getElementsByClassName("item-note-day")[0].textContent = currentItem.data.noteDay;
        result.getElementsByClassName("item-iconClassImage")[0].src = currentItem.data.iconImage;
        result.getElementsByClassName("item-noteTitle")[0].textContent = currentItem.data.noteTitle;
        result.getElementsByClassName("item-noteExcerpt")[0].textContent = currentItem.data.noteContent;
        return result;
```

What i want is when I click the button I insert my data into sqlite and the listview refresh so i can see all my datas include the new one. And I successed insert my data into 
sqlite.

sorry Im a Chinese, this is my first time ask question in English. I dont no am I clear or not? If anyone can help me,thank you.

Comment: Which SQLite component do you use? Since you're not using databinding I suppose that you're also not using a WinJS.UI.ListView? Anyway, I can _really_ recommend using databinding.

Comment: I use WinJS.UI.ListView. Because I need my datas display in listview with different size, so I can`t use databingding. If I use databingding I can`t set my datas in different size I want. this is a sample from msdn. well, If I use databinding how to refresh it? thank you. @ma_il

Comment: You can still use databinding and display different-sized items. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj585523.aspx for that. Anyway, which SQLite component do you use?

Comment: Ok I will try,thank you. about sqlite here is what I use https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT  @ma_il

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this SQLite component, there are two approaches. First, the simple one:

1. use the itemDataSource provided by the component ([see the unit tests](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT/blob/master/SQLite3JS/spec/SQLite3Spec.js#L527) for a sample)
2. call invalidateAll on it when data changes. Either from a [listener registered for insert events](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT/blob/master/SQLite3JS/spec/SQLite3Spec.js#L348) on the database or via application-specific events that trigger it

The problem here is of course that it will always reload the whole list. If you want to have a dynamic list which doesn't hit the database for each update, the second approach would be to implement your own IListDataSource interface, which can become much more complicated. I did this for our app and am currently working on an abstract and reusable version of this for a pet project of mine but unfortunately I can't give any schedule on when this will be ready for a release...